# Importing images at run-time

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

What is the (best) way to import images at runtime in Create-react-app. My app fetches an array from an API containing ~20 image names. How do I load these images into my app on run-time to display them? (there are over 300 images in the image folder, so importing/bundling them all is not a good option).

Comment: What do you mean by `load these images`?
Do you want them to display? Then use `<img>` tag for each image.

Comment: yes indeed, display them. U mean serve them from a static folder and just use 
`src="imageFileName" `?

Comment: if by imagename u mean the image url, then just add it to the src
@RobIndesteege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting a lot of images, I would look at maybe creating a CDN or even just put them in an S3 bucket on AWS. This would reduce load on your website. The image names can be mapped to the names in the S3 bucket as long as they're named the same.